# Can thunderbird with -no-remote launch firefox without it?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, xubuntu

We have two thunderbird profiles, and we launch thunderbird using -no-remote as follows:

```
thunderbird -no-remote -P Profile1
```

and

```
thunderbird -no-remote -P Profile2
```

unfortunately, this means that if either of us click on a link in an email, and firefox is already running, we get a warning message telling us that firefox is already running, rather than having it open the link.

Is it possible for thunderbird to use firefox's remote, even though it has been launched with -no-remote?

(if it makes a difference, this is on Xubuntu Karmic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a script like this. . .

```
#!/bin/bash
unset MOZ_NO_REMOTE
/usr/bin/firefox "$@"
```

Then set **network.protocol-handler.warn-external.http** to "true".

Then launch Thunderbird, click a link, and choose your script.

This works for me on Thunderbird 3.1 on RHEL6.  If I have more than one Firefox profile open, the link is opened in the first Firefox profile I launched.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Firefox does not support that kind of setting inheritance on forked processes, although Mozilla encourage you to [provide feedback and suggestions](http://hendrix.mozilla.org/) for their products.